# Unable to run node API on Ubuntu (AWS)

Tags: node.js, api, ubuntu-16.04

I have deployed node API on Ubuntu server (AWS) but when I run my app it throw below error given in screen shot. due to I am not able to make API requst.

I have trid to kill port and execute it again but it gives e same error
my node app  is running on 8081 on local machine

```
var connection = mongoose

  .connect(url, option)
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(PORT);
    console.log("Running RestHub on port " + PORT)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

after uploading code in Ubuntu sever it does not work
[image]

[image]

I am struggling to fix this issue since yesterday but could not fix yet.

Please your help would be  highly appreciated

Thanks you

Comment: Post output of `netstat -anp | grep 8080`

Comment: @EugenRieck Thanks for the reply I have posted it out

Comment: this is endpoints I am using from my front-en http://xx.x.xx.xx:8082/"

Comment: This proves, that another node instance is already running on port 8080

Comment: might be the same api running but once  I deploy new code its get stopped working

Comment: But the node process ist still listening on that port - have you tried SIGHUP or SIGKILLing it?